# Generar un código en php para hacer tickets con autoincremento

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Mi problema es que no sé como generar tickets con autoincremento pero con identificador, por ejemplo quiero algo que se vea asi "SC-01, SC-02...SC-5000" apenas estoy empezando en la programación, espero me puedan ayudar y dar algun consejo. Gracias

Asi  tengo generado el codigo:

```
<?php
NuevoFormulario($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['numcontrol'], $_POST['carrera']
,$_POST['email'], $_POST['descripcion']);

function NuevoFormulario($nombre,$apellidos,$numcontrol,$carrera,$email,$descripcion)

{
    include 'conexion.php';
// $conexion= conecta_mysql();
    $tickets="CREATE TRIGGER tickets BEFORE INSERT ON `sistemas` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE tickets INT;
    SET tickets = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND `sistemas`=tickets);
  SET NEW.codigo_secundario = CONCAT('SC-', LPAD(tickets, 8, '0'));
END";

$sentencia= "INSERT INTO `sistemas` (`tickets`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `numcontrol`, `carrera`, `email`, `descripcion`)
VALUES ('".$tickets."','".$nombre."','".$apellidos."','".$numcontrol."','".$carrera."','".$email."',
    '".$descripcion."')";


    // $conexion2->query($tickets) or die ("Error al generar el folio".mysqli_error($conexion2));
    $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al enviar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));

}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Enviado exitosamente");
window.location.href='sistemas.html';
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, de casualidad tienes ya realizada la estructura de la tabla en cuestión. Otra cosa, en donde necesitas dar formato a tu identificador, en el query SQL, o en la validación con php?

Comment: Si, ya tengo generada la tabla con los campos correspondientes. necesito la validacion con php, ya agregue el codifgo que tengo en php, si me deja ingresar los datos solo que no me genera lo del ticket

Comment: Haz intentado ejecutar primero el trigger y luego el insert?

Comment: @RicardoCamposVillarroel SÍ, lo estoy intentando pero aún asi me marca error

Comment: Esto es lo que me sale: Error al enviar los datos You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SC-', LPAD(tickets, 8, '0')); END','Mario Alberto','Sanchez Bautista','16350666'' at line 2

Comment: El trigger hay que crearlo **una vez** nada más. Como haces con las tablas, por ejemplo. Ponerlo en el PHP de tu página de tickets hace que lo intentes crear cada vez que usas tu script :/ Se entiende aún menos que pongas ese código EN UN CAMPO de tu insert.

Comment: @Alfabravo ok, lo intentare, me cuesta un poco entender bien ya que soy nuevo en esto de la programación, gracias por su ayuda